# Vectorize code to create a 3-dimensional array consisting of coordinate windows from a coordinate vector

Tags: matlab, indexing, vectorization

I have a coordinate vector `comp_points` holding an image-coordinate-pair in each row. Now I want to create an array `comp_windows` holding `nxm`-windows of an image around the coordinates of `comp_points`. These windows shall be aligned along the 3rd dimension of `comp_windows`.
I solved the task like this:

```
I2=randi([0 255],[500 500]);
comp_points=randi([10 490],[20 2]);
delta_u_window=5;
delta_v_window=5;
for ii=1:size(comp_points,1)
    comp_windows(:,:,ii)=I2(...
        comp_points(ii,1)-delta_u_window:...
        comp_points(ii,1)+delta_u_window,...
        comp_points(ii,2)-delta_v_window:...
        comp_points(ii,2)+delta_v_window);
end
```

Now I feel like I could do this without the `for`-loop using a concatenation or indexing expression or something, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the operations as `slicing` without any compute. So, I am not sure if it's worth to vectorize it, but let's put it out anyway with big help from [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
% Get range arrays
r1 = [-delta_u_window : delta_u_window];
r2 = [-delta_v_window : delta_v_window];

% Get row and column indices for all points in comp_points
r = bsxfun(@plus,r1(:),comp_points(:,1).');
c = bsxfun(@plus,r2(:),comp_points(:,2).');

% Next up, the work is to combine those row and column indices in a meshed-way

% Get 3D version of r and c - Keeping their last dim aligned and "spreading
% out" their first dims against each others. Then, perform elementwise
% summations to give us a summed up array of indices, indexing into which
% would give us the desired output.
r3D = reshape(r,size(r,1),1,[]);
c3D = reshape((c-1)*size(I2,1),1,size(c,1),[]);
out = I2(bsxfun(@plus, r3D, c3D));
```

For `permute` lovers, we can replace the last three steps with a single one, like so -

```
I2(bsxfun(@plus, permute(r,[1,3,2]), permute((c-1)* size(I2,1),[3,1,2])))
```

Comment: Holy hell. Is it worth vectorizing?!! In octave, your solution runs in *0.005* seconds, while the for loop takes *0.3* seconds. I though of a solution based on arrayfun, but it was still arount *0.3*. Tip of my hat to you. This is just beautiful and correct code.

Comment: @Ash Wow, well I guess I underestimated the power of vectorizing here! Thanks for benchmarking and the feedback of course!

Comment: wooops, I forgot to say, this timing corresponds to *10^4* points.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Divakar. Pretty much what I was looking for. To be honest, I'm not even interested in performance here. I'm just looking to improve myself in terms of vectorizing and it bugged me that I was unable to do it here.

Comment: @Ash As far as I know, `arrayfun` will never be faster than usual for-loops. It's just a way to make the code more compact and look fancy.

Comment: @Max Thanks, I'll look it up. I thought that underneath, it would call the function on each row in parallel (well, not on all of them, but in small batches), but apparently I was mistaken. In that case  why even bother to use it? A for loop is far more readable imo.